# Send both image and content to share whatsapp, facebook and email in android?

Tags: android

I know It is already answered, but my question is I have image url, I need to use this Image url and send that pixture to all applications.

This is my image url, I need to send this image and text also.
    http://uniflyn.com/daily_star/uploads/profile/20180315151937.jpg

I used `Uri.parse(http://uniflyn.com/daily_star/uploads/profile/20180315151937.jpg)` but it does not give the result. please help me , if anyone knows the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("Your Image URL"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```